# How can I use useEffect with Suspense in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-suspense

Hello I want to auto focus to input when my page loaded. I have to use Suspense because I using i18n. I have auto focus code but not working well.

```js
<Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen/>}>
  <Input />
</Suspense>
```

```js
const Input = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  return (
    <input ref={inputRef} type="text"/>
  );
};
```

My code working well when I remove suspense. But I need suspense for i18n. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Thy using [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) instead of useEffect.

```
const Input = () => {
  const callbackRef = useCallback(ref => ref && ref.focus());
  return (
    <input ref={callbackRef} type="text"/>
  );
};
```

It didn't work because `useEffect` was called when the component is Mounted which is happens before the `<Suspese />` is completed.

Comment: same problem :( working when re-rendering but not working after refresh the page

Comment: Ok I see where the problem is, Suspense starts rendering as soon as fetching: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#approach-3-render-as-you-fetch-using-suspense

You can try a fix with `useEffect(() => ref.current.focus(), [dataLoaded])` this will trigger the function when you change the state of the dataLoaded

Comment: I think I can create new state with redux and when LoadingScreen component unmounted I set true pageLoaded redux state. And I focus with useEffect when pageLoaded is true. Is it ok?

Comment: I think this will work

Comment: Yeah its work, thanks